# Multiple domains, multiple vhosts, separate rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, dns, vhosts

I am trying to host multiple different rails apps on the same VPS using multiple domains.  I am using Apache 2.2.17 on Ubuntu 10.10.  For Apache, I have multiple vhost files so that I can enable and disable particular sites easily without needing to comment them out or delete them.  In addition, I am also using mod_rewrite so that the multiple domains that go to the same rails app appear to go to the same URL so I don't take a hit with search engines as far as duplicate content.

I believe that my DNS is setup properly.  For each of the domains, I have a `www` subdomain as well as some site-specific sub-domains, such as blogs, etc.  The issue I am seeing is that Apache appears to matching the `www` subdomain immediately and not examining the additional URL behind it.  Changing `ServerAlias` does nothing.  For example, using my setup, if I enter `davidheartsrachel.com`, I properly reach my wedding website.  However, if I use `www.davidheartsrachel.com`, I reach my other website, my software development business.  The URL is not re-written; it stays as `davidheartsrachel.com` instead of `afewguyscoding.com`.

The only way I have been able to properly get it to work is to use mod_rewrite in the primary vhost file to redirect to the wedding website vhost file (you can see that I have that in the primary vhost file, but it is commented out for purposes of this question).  This doesn't seem proper to me?  Should I get another IP and do IP vhosts instead of name-based vhosts?

When I execute `apachectl -S`, I get the following:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server afewguyscoding.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/afewguyscoding.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost afewguyscoding.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/afewguyscoding.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost blog.afewguyscoding.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/afewguyscoding.com:69)
         port 80 namevhost lbbs.afewguyscoding.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/afewguyscoding.com:84)
         port 80 namevhost davidheartsrachel.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/davidheartsrachel.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost dhr.afewguyscoding.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/davidheartsrachel_staging:1)
Syntax OK
```

I notice that `afewguyscoding.com` is the default site - however, doesn't it have to do a full string match to determine the proper site?

**Primary site's vhost file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin david.stites@afewguyscoding.com
  ServerName afewguyscoding.com
  ServerAlias davidstites.com, 5280software.com, milehigh-software.com, milehighsoftware.org
  ServerAlias www.5280software.com, www.milehigh-software.com, www.milehighsoftware.org, www.davidstites.com, www.afewguyscoding.com

  # this tells rails that it will run in production mode
  # this is for rails < 3.x
  RailsEnv production

  DocumentRoot /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/public
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  # custom log file locations
  # possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel alert
  ErrorLog  /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/log/access.log combined

  # allows compression of text based mime.types
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  FileETag None
  RewriteEngine On

  # check for maintenance file and redirect all requests
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ws/
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /system/maintenance.html

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.davidheartsrachel.com$
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://davidheartsrachel.com$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.davidstites.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.afewguyscoding.com$1 [R=301,L]

  <Directory /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  # In case I ever need CGI
  #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  #<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
  #     AllowOverride None
  #     Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  #     Order allow,deny
  #     Allow from all
  #</Directory>

  # how we can restrict access to documents from the local subnet
  #Order deny,allow
  #Deny from all
  #Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128

  <Location /blog>
    PassengerEnabled off
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@afewguyscoding.com
  ServerName blog.afewguyscoding.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/wpress
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Wedding site's vhost file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@davidheartsrachel.com
  ServerName davidheartsrachel.com
  ServerAlias rachelanddavid.net, rachelanddavidstites.com, rachelanddavidwedding.com
  ServerAlias www.davidheartsrachel.com, www.rachelanddavidstites.com, www.rachelanddavidwedding.com, www.rachelanddavid.net

  # this tells rails that it will run in production mode
  # this is for rails < 3.x
  RailsEnv production
  # this is for rails >= 3.x
  RackEnv production

  DocumentRoot /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/public
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  # Custom log file locations
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert and emerg,
  LogLevel alert
  ErrorLog  /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/log/access.log combined

  # Allows compression of text based mime types
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  FileETag None
  RewriteEngine On

  # Check for maintenance file and redirect all requests
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif)$
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /system/maintenance.html [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rachelanddavidwedding.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.davidheartsrachel.com$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rachelanddavidstites.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.davidheartsrachel.com$1 [R=301,L]

  # Static cache
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
  RewriteCond /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/tmp/cache/static$1/index.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/tmp/cache/static$1/index.html [L]

  <Directory /var/www/davidheartsrachel/current/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you can think of any more information that might be helpful, please, ask me to post it.

**Edit:**

Let me try to clear this up. In the most essential form, my question is: why does going to davidheartsrachel.com takes you to www.afewguyscoding.com and davidheartsrachel.com takes you to davidheartsrachel.com based on my configuration above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was incorrectly separating the entries under ServerAlias with a comma thusly:

```
ServerAlias rachelanddavid.net, rachelanddavidstites.com, rachelanddavidwedding.com, www.davidheartsrachel.com, www.rachelanddavidstites.com, www.rachelanddavidwedding.com, www.rachelanddavid.net
```

It is supposed to be a space:

```
ServerAlias rachelanddavid.net rachelanddavidstites.com rachelanddavidwedding.com www.davidheartsrachel.com www.rachelanddavidstites.com www.rachelanddavidwedding.com www.rachelanddavid.net
```

Answer (score 0):

On my servers I don't define a primary site in my main httpd.conf file. I do all the virtual hosting in separate application specific conf files.

The only thing I have in my main httpd.conf is the line `NameVirtualHost *:80`

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/1052175) of a way you could try it. I pulled all the wedding site configuration out of your main site configuration. I set it so davidstites.com, afewguyscoding.com, and www.davidstites.com all redirect to www.afewguyscoding.com. The other domains (milehigh et al) are unaffected. I'm not sure where you wanted those to go.

All the wedding related domains redirect to www.davidheartsrachel.com.

I did notice what I think might have been a mess up in your main site configuration. Toward the end where you set your directory permissions you were using the /var/www/afewguyscoding/current/public directory instead of the /var/www/wpress that is the DocumentRoot. The correction I made there is on line 74 of the first document in that gist.

Comment: So redirecting would be proper for sites that should be grouped together.  However, I wouldn't want to 301 redirect for a site that is completely different, i.e., in my case where I have a vhost for my software site and a vhost for my wedding website.  It just seems wrong to mix in redirects for a completely separate vhost in another vhost file.

Comment: Define websites that shouldn't be grouped together in their own VirtualHosts. There's no redirecting. I have up to 30 domains on servers, some grouped together, some aren't. I only have one IP address per server.

Comment: That is what I have done, if you look at my original post.  Note the two different vhost files.  The issue is that somehow, it is not matching the full URL - it sees www and automatically chooses the "primary" vhost, afewguyscoding.com, regardless of the TLD following the www.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're mixing the wedding sites virtualhost configurations into the primary sites configuration.

Comment: I am *trying* not to.  However "the issue I am seeing is that Apache appears to matching the www subdomain of afewguyscoding.com immediately and not examining the additional URL behind it. Changing ServerAlias does nothing. For example, using my setup, if I enter davidheartsrachel.com, I properly reach my wedding website. However, if I use www.davidheartsrachel.com, I reach my other website, my software development business."  Mixing them is the only way I can properly get it to work.  I am trying to get them to work without mixing them.

Comment: Let me try to clear this up.  In the most essential form, my question is: why does going to http://www.davidheartsrachel.com/ takes you to www.afewguyscoding.com and http://davidheartsrachel.com/ takes you to http://www.davidheartsrachel.com/ based on my configuration above.

Comment: If you're willing to try out the way I'd do it, I edited my answer with what you could do.

Comment: I disabled all of my versions completely, copied and pasted yours verbatim from github, re-enabled and reloaded Apache, and I am still getting the same results: entering `www.davidheartsrachel.com` takes you to `www.afewguyscoding.com` and entering `davidheartsrachel.com` takes you to `www.davidheartsrachel.com`.  I have your versions enabled at those URLs right now if you would like to try going to them.

Comment: I have also included my httpd.conf, apache2.conf and hosts files because there is obviously something else going on besides this vhost file: https://gist.github.com/1052303

Comment: And last but not least - here are my DNS zone files: https://gist.github.com/1052309

Comment: It's been a while since I read a whole httpd.conf. I don't see anything glaringly wrong in there, unless you're accidentally including something that's screwing it up. Try commenting out every rewritecond/rewriterule in both those conf files and see if you end up on the right app for each domain without any redirecting. Let's start there so we can make sure it's not a setting in some other file.

Comment: Interestingly, I am still seeing the same behavior.  These files are currently loaded in Apache.  They are based off of the files you gave me and I removed all mod_rewrite directives.  Something is definitely weird here.  https://gist.github.com/1052340.  Thanks for all your help, btw.  Disabling mod_rewrite doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: This is a long shot, but while I'm looking through it some more, try clearing your browser's cache or use a different browser. Maybe your browser is remembering something.

Comment: Why do you configure all that in your hosts file?

Comment: It was recommended in some of the setup tutorials I read. Certainly, I can remove it.  And as you suspected, no luck on clearing the cache.

Comment: Taking those entries out of the hosts file didn't make a difference.  I might consider installing nginx to see if I still have the problem which would definitely isolate it to Apache.

Comment: Oh I'm sure it's apache, I just can't figure where.

Comment: Interestingly, a `hostname` reveals `plato` and a `hostname -f` reveals `www.afewguyscoding.com`. Could that be it?

Comment: I could always completely remove the Apache installation and re-do it from scratch.

Comment: @davidstites let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/979/discussion-between-preacher-and-davidstites)